# how to change map marker color for each type in google map api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am trying to display Atm locations near by search area using Google places and autocomplete. its working fine and map showing atm and bank locations correctly but its showing same map marker, i want to know how to show different color  marker for each type. below is my code.

```
var map, places, iw;
  var markers = [];
  var autocomplete;

  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(17.717063, 83.300310);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', tilesLoaded);
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      showSelectedPlace();
    });
  }

  function tilesLoaded() {
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'tilesloaded');
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', search);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', search);
    search();
  }

  function showSelectedPlace() {
    clearResults();
    clearMarkers();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
    markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: place.geometry.location,
      map: map
    });
    iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: getIWContent(place)
    });
    iw.open(map, markers[0]);
  }

  function search() {
    var type;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.controls.type.length; i++) {
      if (document.controls.type[i].checked) {
        type = document.controls.type[i].value;
      }
    }

    autocomplete.setBounds(map.getBounds());

    var search = {
      bounds: map.getBounds()
    };

    if (type != 'establishment') {
      search.types = [ type ];
    }

    places.search(search, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        clearResults();
        clearMarkers();
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[i].geometry.location,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', getDetails(results[i], i));
          setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
          addResult(results[i], i);
        }
      }
    })
  }

  function clearMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      if (markers[i]) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
        markers[i] == null;
      }
    }
  }

  function dropMarker(i) {
    return function() {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }

  function addResult(result, i) {
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.style.backgroundColor = (i% 2 == 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');
    tr.onclick = function() {
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
    };

    var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
    var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
    var icon = document.createElement('img');
    icon.src = result.icon;
    icon.setAttribute("class", "placeIcon");
    icon.setAttribute("className", "placeIcon");
    var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
    iconTd.appendChild(icon);
    nameTd.appendChild(name);
    tr.appendChild(iconTd);
    tr.appendChild(nameTd);
    results.appendChild(tr);
  }

  function clearResults() {
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    while (results.childNodes[0]) {
      results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
    }
  }

  function getDetails(result, i) {
    return function() {
      places.getDetails({
          reference: result.reference
      }, showInfoWindow(i));
    }
  }

  function showInfoWindow(i) {
    return function(place, status) {
      if (iw) {
        iw.close();
        iw = null;
      }

      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: getIWContent(place)
        });
        iw.open(map, markers[i]);        
      }
    }
  }

  function getIWContent(place) {
    var content = "";
    content += '<table class="style_infowin"><tr><td>';
    content += '<img class="placeIcon" src="' + place.icon + '"/></td>';
    content += '<td><b><a href="' + place.url + '">' + place.name + '</a></b>';
    content += '<tr class="iw_table_row"><td class="iw_attribute_name">Address:</td><td>' + place.vicinity + '</td></tr>';
    content += '</td></tr></table>';
    return content;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the markersi color but you can change the marker icon see marker class reference for check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

You can change the icon with

```
  marker.setIcon('newImage.png');
```

or you can create the marker with proper icon

> ```
>  var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
>  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>     position: myLatLng,
>     map: map,
>     icon: iconBase + 'schools_maps.png'    });
> ```

this is from google doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/custom-markers#try_it_out

Answer (score 0):

The Place Result contains an icon URL for each result.  One option would be to use those.

```
places.search(search, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    clearResults();
    clearMarkers();
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[i].geometry.location,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: { url: results[i].icon, scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20,20)}
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', getDetails(results[i], i));
      setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
      addResult(results[i], i);
    }
  }
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dpa4taL9/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map, places, iw;
var markers = [];
var autocomplete;

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(17.717063, 83.300310);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', tilesLoaded);
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    showSelectedPlace();
  });
}

function tilesLoaded() {
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'tilesloaded');
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', search);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', search);
  search();
}

function showSelectedPlace() {
  clearResults();
  clearMarkers();
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
  markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: place.geometry.location,
    map: map
  });
  iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: getIWContent(place)
  });
  iw.open(map, markers[0]);
}

function search() {
  var type = 'atm';
  /* for (var i = 0; i < document.controls.type.length; i++) {
    if (document.controls.type[i].checked) {
      type = document.controls.type[i].value;
    }
  } */

  autocomplete.setBounds(map.getBounds());

  var search = {
    bounds: map.getBounds()
  };

  if (type != 'establishment') {
    search.types = [type];
  }

  places.search(search, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      clearResults();
      clearMarkers();
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: results[i].geometry.location,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: {
            url: results[i].icon,
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20)
          }
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', getDetails(results[i], i));
        setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
        addResult(results[i], i);
      }
    }
  })
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i]) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
      markers[i] == null;
    }
  }
}

function dropMarker(i) {
  return function() {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

function addResult(result, i) {
  var results = document.getElementById("results");
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.style.backgroundColor = (i % 2 == 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');
  tr.onclick = function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
  };

  var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
  var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
  var icon = document.createElement('img');
  icon.src = result.icon;
  icon.setAttribute("class", "placeIcon");
  icon.setAttribute("className", "placeIcon");
  var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
  iconTd.appendChild(icon);
  nameTd.appendChild(name);
  tr.appendChild(iconTd);
  tr.appendChild(nameTd);
  results.appendChild(tr);
}

function clearResults() {
  var results = document.getElementById("results");
  while (results.childNodes[0]) {
    results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
  }
}

function getDetails(result, i) {
  return function() {
    places.getDetails({
      reference: result.reference
    }, showInfoWindow(i));
  }
}

function showInfoWindow(i) {
  return function(place, status) {
    if (iw) {
      iw.close();
      iw = null;
    }

    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: getIWContent(place)
      });
      iw.open(map, markers[i]);
    }
  }
}

function getIWContent(place) {
  var content = "";
  content += '<table class="style_infowin"><tr><td>';
  content += '<img class="placeIcon" height="20" width="20" src="' + place.icon + '"/></td>';
  content += '<td><b><a href="' + place.url + '">' + place.name + '</a></b>';
  content += '<tr class="iw_table_row"><td class="iw_attribute_name">Address:</td><td>' + place.vicinity + '</td></tr>';
  content += '</td></tr></table>';
  return content;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.placeIcon {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.cols {
  -webkit-columns: 3 150px;
  -moz-columns: 3 150px;
  columns: 3 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="autocomplete" />
<div class="cols" id="results"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```